# An example of a Lebesgue measurable set which is not a Borel set and why?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, cantor-set, borel-sets

Could anyone please give me an example of a Lebesgue measurable set which is not a Borel set and explain to me why?

I guess it is the Cantor-Lebesgue set, but I am unable to say why. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What's Cantor-Lebesgue set?

Comment: @Wojowu. It IS a duplicate.

Comment: The Cantor set is defined as the intersection of a countable collection of closed sets, so it is a Borel set.